# Python Pandas -- Determine if Values in Column 0 Are Repeated in Each Subsequent Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tuples

I have a collection of internet-connected devices hanging around in various places. I have a dataframe that contains seven rows, one for each day in the past week. Each row contains the serial number of each device that didn't connect to my server that day. I am trying to compile a report that creates an 8th row, which contains the serial number of each device that failed to communicate for seven straight days. Here is a simplified mock-up of my dataframe:

```
2016-10-01, AAAA, BBBB, CCCC, EEEE
2016-10-02, AAAA, BBBB, EEEE,
2016-10-03, AAAA, BBBB, CCCC, EEEE
2016-10-04, AAAA, BBBB, CCCC, EEEE
2016-10-05, BBBB, CCCC, DDDD, EEEE
2016-10-06, AAAA, BBBB, CCCC, EEEE
2016-10-07, AAAA, BBBB, CCCC, FFFF
```

Here is the code block that is giving me problems. I am trying to compare the values in the first column with the values of each of the other columns. If I get 6 `Trues`, I add the serial number to a new `list` then try to tack that on to the dataframe.

```
cursor = localConnection.cursor()
cursor.execute(allInstalledQuery % ('', fac[0]))
cursor.fetchall()
totalDevices = cursor.rowcount
cursor.close()
for i in range(7, 0, -1):
    loopCursor = localConnection.cursor()
    print(i)
    sns = []
    d = datetime.datetime.strptime(todayDate, "%Y-%m-%d") + datetime.timedelta(days=-i)
    sns.append(d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    if i != 1:
        loopCursor.execute(missingReportQuery % (i, 1, i, 1, '', fac[0]))
    else:
        loopCursor.execute(missingReportQuery % (i, 0, i, 0, '', fac[0]))
        rows = loopCursor.fetchall()
        numMissing = loopCursor.rowcount
        missingSummary = "%d / %d devices missing"
        sns.append(staleSummary % (nummissing, totaldevices))
        for row in rows:
            sns.append(row[4])
    masterList.append(sns)
    loopCursor.close()

df = pandas.DataFrame(masterList)
```

EDIT The following code block is depricated:

```
firstDayData = df.iloc[[0], :].values
missingSevenDays = []

for s in firstDayData:
    print(s)
    a = pandas.Series(df[1])
    b = pandas.Series(df[2])
    c = pandas.Series(df[3])
    d = pandas.Series(df[4])
    e = pandas.Series(df[5])
    sn = list(str(s))
    if a.isin(sn) is True and b.isin(sn) is True and c.isin(sn) is True and d.isin(sn) is True \
            and e.isin(sn) is True:
        missingSevenDays.append(sn)
df.append(missingSevenDays)
```

AND has been replaced by this:

```
counts = df.stack().value_counts()
seven_day = counts[counts == 7]
filtered_df = df[seven_day.index]
missingSevenDays = []
for neat in filtered_df.values:
    print(neat)
```

I want this to print out the serial number of all devices that have been missing for 7 days. As it stands, it is just printing out `[]`. I'm afraid I'm completely bewildered as to how to use these data structures.

Comment: Can you post raw data and code to create your df, it's unclear if we're dealing with 4 columns or 1 column

Comment: It's 4 columns in the sample code. It can be over 100 columns in my real data. The number of columns is equal to the number of non-reporting devices on that day.

I'm adding in the dataframe creation logic to my original post.

Comment: You could do `df.stack().value_counts()` and this will return the count of each device, any that aren't 7 means it didn't connect for 7 days

Comment: @EdChum That sounds promising.

Comment: @EdChum This seemed to work, but I'm not sure what format the data is now in. How do I process the results of the output of df.stack().value_counts() to get the values of all serial numbers with a count of 7?

Comment: difficult to answer unless you post a representative example that is runnable, basically you can do something like `counts = df.stack().value_counts() seven_day = counts[counts==7] filtered_df = df[seven_day.index]` if you understand