# Python Pandas Using dataframe.stack().value_counts() -- How to get values of counted objects?

Tags: python, loops, pandas, indexing, series

I have a data frame that in which every row represents a day of the week, and every column represents the serial number of an internet-connected device that failed to communicate with the server on that day.

I am trying to get a Series of serial numbers that have failed to communicate for a full week.

The code block:

```
counts = df.stack().value_counts()
seven_day = counts[counts == 7]
for a in seven_day:
    print(a)
```

The problem is that nothing is printed. What I want is a list of the serial numbers, and not the counts themselves.

This question is a follow-up from: 
[Python Pandas -- Determine if Values in Column 0 Are Repeated in Each Subsequent Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40244094/python-pandas-determine-if-values-in-column-0-are-repeated-in-each-subsequent)

Comment: You want to iterate over the index `seven_day = counts[counts == 7]
for a in seven_day.index:
    print(a)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) returns a Series with the values as the index and the counts as the values, so you want to iterate over the index:

```
counts = df.stack().value_counts()
seven_day = counts[counts == 7]
for a in seven_day.index:
    print(a)
```

should work

Comment: That is it. Thank you @EdChum for helping me out so much on both of these questions.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is use [`Series.iteritems`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iteritems.html):

```
counts = df.stack().value_counts()
seven_day = counts[counts == 7]

for index, val in seven_day.iteritems():
    print(index)
```